# ThreadPoolTaskExecutor should Finish Task Queue before Main thread ends

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot

Problem statement:
I have 1,000 tasks and need to process them via ThreadPoolTaskExecutor. ThreadPoolTaskExecutor has `corePoolSize = 5`, `maxPoolSize = 10` and `queueCapacity = 1000`.

Now from the main method, I am executing the following code

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(5);
Collection<Future<?>> futures = new LinkedList<Future<?>>();

for (Map.Entry<String,Boolean> entry : map.entrySet()){
    FutureTask task = new FutureTask(new CustomTask(entry));
    executor.execute(task);
}

log.info("ACTIVE COUNT : "+executor.getActiveCount());
log.info("SIZE of the QUEUE : "+executor.getThreadPoolExecutor().getQueue().size());
log.info("LATCH WAIT  : "+latch.getCount());
latch.wait();

.....

@Override
public Object call() throws Exception {
    latch.countDown();
    //some logic
    return entry;
}
```

Now, the map has 1,000 entries in it and I want to process all tasks in queue(1,000) and then print these log lines. Whats happening here is, the corePoolSize(`which is equal to the CountDounLatch count`) create this number of thread and executes them **'Right-Away'**. However, when this number is hit, it starts filling up the queue(which is totally fine and desired). However, this queue tasks are processed **ONLY AFTER** the main thread reaches the end, only then these tasks start executing. This is something that I don't want. I want the Executor to start picking up items from queue **as soon as threads get free from processing** batch-1.
But in my case, once the batch-1 is processed, the next task is picked only when the main threads ends(which I do not want).

Anyone with a solution on how can this be achieved? (The processing of queue as soon as the thread is available for processing)

P.S : I do understand that latch.await() waits for the threads to complete their execution, but I am looking for a behavior in which **it should wait for all the threads to be finished(which is happening) and all the queue should be empty(my expectations).**

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to do it this way, you need to initialize the latch with the number of tasks that you are going to submit; i.e. 1,000.   Also you should decrement the latch at the end of each task, not at its start (as your code currently seems to be doing.)

But you don't need a latch or a counter or anything to implement this.  Instead, if you are using a Java SE `ExecutorService` directly, just do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Submit lots of tasks

    executorService.shutdown();
    try {
        // Waits until all tasks in the queue have completed
        executorService.awaitTermination(1_000_000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        // OK ... will end now
    }
}
```

And if you are using the SpringFramework specific `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Submit lots of tasks
    
    executor.setAwaitTerminationSeconds(1_000_000);
    executor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
    executor.shutdown();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and having a look at it. You are right, latch decrement is misplaced. Once it is rightly placed, the latch.awaits() worked perfectly. However the main problem still persisted, which is, to end the queue before terminating the main thread. I tried your code snipped for `awaitTermination`, but it gives me the option of `setAwaitTerminationSeconds`. Even when I set this to any seconds, the behavior is the same, which is, the queue gets processed after the main thread ends. Voting up for identifying misplaced latch decrement.

Comment: According to the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), the method name is `awaitTermination(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)`.  If you don't see that method for `executor`, check how you have declared it.  It should be declared as an `ExecutorService` ... not an `Executor`.  Then you can use it as per my answer.

Comment: `private final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor;` coming from `org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent`
So this is my declaration, i believe i am using incorrect class, let me try with `ExecutorService` and see the results.
Thank you again for having a look at it, means alot.

Comment: Ah ... oh.  I thought you were using the standard Java SE `ThreadPoolExecutor` class.  Well that changes things.    See the updated answer.